# How to change the width of specific GUI table column or how to resize it to contents

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qwidget, qtablewidget

[image]
This is the image of the table, In this table the second column width has to be adjusted according to the size of the contents

```
    self.defectTableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame_8)
    self.defectTableWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
    self.defectTableWidget.setObjectName("defectTableWidget")
    self.defectTableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    self.defectTableWidget.setRowCount(2)

    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.defectTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.defectTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.defectTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.defectTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.defectTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.defectTableWidget)
    # header = self.defectTableWidget.horizontalHeader()
    # header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)



                self.defectTableWidget.insertRow(0)
                self.defectTableWidget.setItem(0, 0, 
QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.total_count)))
                self.defectTableWidget.setItem(0, 1, 
QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(elem['label']))
                self.defectTableWidget.setItem(0, 2, 
QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Line1"))
                self.defectTableWidget.setItem(0, 3, 
QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(cur_dateTime))
                self.defectTableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 4, ImgWidget(self))
```

I have tried so many things and nothing worked for me. So can anyone plaese help me with some pieces of code.

Comment: How are you adding items to the table?

Comment: I have updated the code from there you can understand how I am updating the items. Actually, for that, I am using different python file

Comment: I'm confused here. Which version of pyqt are you using? In the additional code you use `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` as it was in pyqt4 instead of `QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem` as it is in pyqt5.

Comment: Heike, I am using pyqt5, Do you have any idea, I am also very confused now.

Comment: In that case `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` should give an error.

Comment: Do you have any kind of suggestion which could solve this?

Comment: You could try using `QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem` instead of `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem`. I suspect that the items added to your table are not standard `QTableWidgetItem`'s since those are part of `pyqt5.QtWidgets` not og `pyqt5.QtGui`.

Comment: @AdithyaRaj provide a [mre]

Comment: Heike, It is great discussing with you, Shall we have a chat. Actually I want to solve this issue today itself.